# Unable to see "Run Test with Code Coverage" Option in Android Studio 3.5.1

Tags: android, junit, code-coverage

I am unable to see Run With Coverage option in Android Studio 3.5.1. Running one simple Unit Test doesn't provide any option either. testCoverageEnabled is also enabled. I wonder if IntelliJ have removed this option.

[image]

Comment: test or androidTest ? I have this option only in 'test' package. Using android studio 3.5.2